# Dynamic popup window at the center with close button

Tags: wpf, popup

I have a button in the window. When I click the button it should show the control in the popup near to the button and when the popup is open the parent window should be disabled. As we are creating a custom control I have to achieve it in the code-behind.

I tried the below code. pop is opening but in the top left corner and without the close button.

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Button button = new Button();
        button.Width = 130;
        button.Content = "Table";
        button.Click += _buttonClicked;
        MyDock.Children.Add(button);
    }

    private void _buttonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.IsEnabled = false;
        DataGrid simpleTable = new DataGrid();
        simpleTable.ItemsSource = "ss,d,dd,ggg,rr,tt,yy".Split(',').Select(x => new Item() { Value = x }).ToList();
        DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
        textColumn.Width = new DataGridLength(60, DataGridLengthUnitType.Pixel);
        simpleTable.Style = (Style)this.Resources["DataGridStyle"];
        textColumn.Binding = new Binding("Value");
        textColumn.ElementStyle = (Style)this.Resources["TextColumn"];
        simpleTable.Columns.Add(textColumn);
        Popup codePopup = new Popup();

        codePopup.Child = simpleTable;
        codePopup.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        codePopup.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        codePopup.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Center;
        codePopup.IsOpen = true;

        this.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: post your xaml too

Comment: Xaml for popup window?

Answer (score 0):

For your popup, you need to implement Buttons to close by yourself. Popups do not include a build-in close Button. Maybe you can use another control like a messagebox or anything else if you don't want to implement it by yourself.

For the positioning, you should add an PlacementTarget like this: `codePopup.PlacementTarget = MyDock;` so the popup knows the related UIControl.

Comment: how to disable the parent window?

Comment: What you have done is correct, but you enable it on the last line of the button_clicked handler again. The enable should be done in the close event handler of the popup, not in the opening of the popup. The code is not waiting for you to close the popup again in this case. If you don't want to implement it all by yourself, you can use a framework like Prism for this with InteractionRequestTriggers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.interactivity.interactionrequest.interactionrequesttrigger(v=pandp.50).aspx

Comment: Even though Disabling the parent window is not working

Comment: What do you mean by is not working? In my case, the button for showing the popup is not clockable because it is disabled. What else do you want to accomplish?

Comment: no, i want to make the window to be inaccessible with the popup is open.

Comment: I think for this you can't use the popup. In this case use a custom MessageBox (how to write a custom Messagebox: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1081930/Custom-Message-Box-in-WPF-XAML ) and show it on top of your window with `MessageBox.Show(this, "TitleOfBox");`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a modal dialog window. Try this:

```
private void _buttonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid simpleTable = new DataGrid();
    simpleTable.ItemsSource = "ss,d,dd,ggg,rr,tt,yy".Split(',').Select(x => new Item() { Value = x }).ToList();
    DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
    textColumn.Width = new DataGridLength(60, DataGridLengthUnitType.Pixel);
    simpleTable.Style = (Style)this.Resources["DataGridStyle"];
    textColumn.Binding = new Binding("Value");
    textColumn.ElementStyle = (Style)this.Resources["TextColumn"];
    simpleTable.Columns.Add(textColumn);

    Window codePopup = new Window();
    codePopup.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
    codePopup.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow;
    codePopup.Owner = this;
    codePopup.Content = simpleTable;
    codePopup.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
    codePopup.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    codePopup.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
    codePopup.ShowDialog();
}
```

The `ShowDialog()` method won't return until the popup window has been closed, which effectively means that the `MainWindow` will be disabled until then.

Comment: Yes. But Windows theme is different so i cant go for window show.

Comment: You can re-style the window to make it look however you want: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/16/how-to-create-a-custom-window-in-wpf/. A Popup doesn't have any close button and also it's not modal.